# AWS ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI ec2 volume policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to tag ec2 volumes using the ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI, but I receive a 403 response for the attempt. So it's clear that I don't have permissions for it, so I tried it with wildcard policy arn "*" and "*" action and it worked, so that's the problem. This policy does work with tagging ec2 instances however.

What am I missing in this policy to use this API on volumes?

```
{  
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[  
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "tag:*",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
         ],
         "Resource":[  
            "*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would this this would allow everything I need, but maybe volumes need something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `ec2:CreateTags` permission. See this [reference](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/ec2.html)

Comment: This was the solution, Thanks! It seems odd though, that the documentation for the API suggests that anything that is taggable should be able to be tagged by ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI. Or at least it shouldn't work for tagging instances like it does.